# Telegram problems with updates

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a simple bot for Telegram, I have settled the webhook correctly.
My problem is that I'm not able to get updates using `file_get_contents("php://input")`. I obtain the JSON object only if I use `file_get_contents($mywebsite."/getUpdates");` and in that way I'm able to obtain the info of the chat.
Anyway I can send messages only if I reload my web page and not directly from the Telegram app.
How can I fix this problem?